# Does Datastax dsbulk tool duplicates or upsert data when previously loaded file reloaded?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

Does Datastax dsbulk duplicates or upsert data when previously loaded file reloaded?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question was related to basics of dsbulk tool, will it append the same records again, that is duplicate records or upsert the existing records, if say the same file is reloaded again. If I correctly understand you are saying it will duplicate the existing data as it will append the same records from the file again, which was earlier loaded successfully. It that understanding correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the feature that allows a failed operation to be resumed, which was introduced in 1.10.

If so, yes, there is a risk of inserting the same row twice. There is no risk of missing a row though.

As a consequence, you should only use this feature if your data is idempotent, or if you don't care about having duplicates in the database.